# Input on planned diet/exercise regime

Tags: weight-loss, diet

Just Googling, my BMR is ~1500cals, so I'll try to keep my daily intake to that. I'll aim to eat ~80-100g protein a day, ~100-150g carb and spread meals out 2-4 hours with each meal ~300 cals.

Sample meal plan for a day (spaces out 2-4 hours, I'm guestimating the macros):

Oatmeal, scrambled egg whites, strawberries (200cal, 25g carb, 10g protein)
 - 2 Greek Yogurt cups (160 cal, 20g carb, 24g protein)
 - Orgain Protein Powder, fruit (200 cal, 30g carb, 25g protein)
 - Cooked chicken, vegetables (350 cal, 15g carb, 30g protein)

I realize I'm short of my nutrition macros/cals, but I literally can't think of any other foods that are easy to pack/make on a busy college student schedule and budget. Suggestions?

For working out, I plan to do either strength/cardio on alternating days. Pretty standard. I'll plan to time high-protein after working out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calorie intake is aroung ~2000cals for maintenance and ~1500cals for losing weight (around 1lb/per week).

As far as you are aiming for weight loss i suggest a 40carb/30protein/30fat macros ratio. For you that means 160gr/120gr/53gr.

Considering that you are an athlete you should have a proper diet.

**Breakfast**

- 1 Whole Egg
- 2 Egg Whites
- 50gr Oats

**After Workout**

- 1 Scoop of Protein
- 1 banana

**Lunch**

- 40gr Rice Raw (or 250gr Potato/ or 40gr Whole Wheat Pasta Raw but
  that could be better around 2-3 times/per week)
- 70gr Chicken Breast Raw (or Turkey/ or Beef/Calf but also around 2-3
  times/ per week / or Pork but that could be better around 1
  time/2weeks / you can also add fish like fresh
  tuna/salmon/tilapia/cod / or your prefered legumes)
- 10ml Olive Oil
- Salad ( prefer green salads or vegetables like lettuce/broccoli and kale/ cauliflower, in general have a salad with your meal, don't think too much about the portion eat much as you want - in general terms)

**Middle Meal**

- 250gr Potato Raw (or 40gr Rice Raw/ or 40gr Whole Wheat Pasta Raw but
  that could be better around 2-3 times/per week)
- 70gr Chicken Breast Raw (or Turkey/ or Beef/Calf but also around 2-3
  times/ per week / or Pork but that could be better around 1
  time/2weeks / you can also add fish like fresh
  tuna/salmon/tilapia/cod / or your prefered legumes)
- 10ml Olive Oil
- Salad ( prefer green salads or vegetables like lettuce/broccoli and kale/ cauliflower, in general have a salad with your meal, don't think too much about the portion eat much as you want - in general terms)

**Dinner**

- 40gr Rice Raw (or 250gr Potato/ or 40gr Whole Wheat Pasta Raw but
  that could be better around 2-3 times/per week)
- 70gr Chicken Breast Raw (or Turkey/ or Beef/Calf but also around 2-3
  times/ per week / or Pork but that could be better around 1
  time/2weeks / you can also add fish like fresh
  tuna/salmon/tilapia/cod / or your prefered legumes)
- 10ml Olive Oil
- Salad ( prefer green salads or vegetables like lettuce/broccoli and kale/ cauliflower, in general have a salad with your meal, don't think too much about the portion eat much as you want - in general terms)

**Before Bed**

- 200gr Greek Yogurt
- 20gr Almonds (or Nuts/Walnuts/Peanuts as far as they are roasted-not
  salted)

That diet would be around 1500cals 160grs of Carbs / 120 grams of Protein / 55grs of Fat.

**Notes:**

- Organize your time and your meals, have a meal around every 3-4
  hours. You can chande the after workout meal at any time you're
  working out.
- Don't get paranoid with grams and macros, as far as you are sure at
  around 90%.
- Measure your food and weight the amounts you eat.
- Be tricky and play with the combinations in order not to get bored
  and give it up.

**Preparation:**

You can spend one day, when you have time like Sunday, and prepare food for the week or for 3-4 days. Then you would be flexible and you would be able to carry your food at any time.

***Important***

Follow this diet plan for as long as you keep losing weight, only when you hit a plateau and you cannot lose more weight (if you want to) then we can discuss it again. Till then eat well and train well.

You should be sure that you are doing cardio at least 4 times/per week. Also weightlifting or strength training 3-4 times/per week is necessary.

Comment: Great post, however you are missing out on veg on every meal!

Comment: @JJosaur Thanks for reminding me this. I took it as granted and forgot to mention it. I edited now!